# These seemingly equivalent API calls using curl returns different results

Tags: api, curl

I have a simple toy API that echoes the input. Upon playing with it I noticed that

`curl --request POST --url http://0.0.0.0:8888/api/v1/dummy --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{ "message": [ "Hello. " ]}'` , copied from my Confluence markup returns an error

```
Bad Request

Bad URI

(generated by waitress)curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
```

while the seemingly verbatim equivalent command, typed out

`curl --request POST --url http://0.0.0.0:8888/api/v1/dummy --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{ "message": [ "Hello. " ]}'`
works fine:

```
{
  "sentences": [
    "Hello. "
  ]
}
```

It sure is confusing, so I'm attaching a screenshot of my terminal:

[Two seemingly equivalent API calls return different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEOLC.png)

Any insight is appreciated. Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `0.0.0.0` like that is incorrect; it's nominally used when specifying the listening address, indicating to listen on any address. Use the actual IP address of the server instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists when I use the actual address. Another thing I discovered is that when I copy the not-working command to MS Word and then again to terminal, it works. So perhaps some encoding issues?

Comment: Possibly, try just typing it out and see.

Comment: Typing the command works out fine. I've been suspecting some kind of markup encoding because I can recreate the non-working command by pasting a working command into places like here and Confluence (and vice versa), but I just want to know why because to me the two commands look exactly the same... I guess I could try out some combinatorial experiment to narrow the character-culprit down.

Comment: Things that I've seen get screwed up by autoformatting are generally quotes and turning double dashes into a single long dash. If you're terminal app is not accepting pasted content without modifying it, it would be worth looking through the settings for anything relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was in the whitespace. The first erroneous command included `&nbsp;`,

```
curl --request POST --url http://0.0.0.0:8888/api/v1/dummy&nbsp;--header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{ "message":&nbsp;[ "Hello. " ]}'
```

while the second functioning command uses a regular whitespace  :

```
curl --request POST --url http://0.0.0.0:8888/api/v1/dummy --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{ "message": [ "Hello. " ]}'
```

You can check the difference by using the inspect (F12) mini-window on Chrome and other browsers.

This explains how Confluence's markup is involved, and why pasting the erroneous command into word and then again into CLI worked.

Thanks to msbit for the helpful discussion.